# Is it possible to use the Google api dotnet client libraries for C# / UWP to query for Youtube Analytics realtime views?

Tags: c#, uwp, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I am putting together a Windows 10 UWP app and need to get realtime views for YouTube channels using the YouTube analytics api.

I can successfully get views using the [Google-api-donet-client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTubeAnalytics.v1/) libraries, but not realtime views.  Basically, the last 48 hours or so are missing.

Using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.channel.Statistics.ViewCount gives me total channel views, a good start.

Using Google.Apis.YouTubeAnalytics.v1 I can do an analytics query

```
var analyticsRequest = youTubeAnalyticsService.Reports.Query(
  myChannelID,
  myStartDate,
  myEndDate,
  myMetrics
);
```

All works successfully, using views as metric.  Just is not realtime, meaning the last couple of days are not there.  Documentation actually states this so there is nothing actually wrong.

Now, I have also tried the Google API Explorer tool, and that exhibits the same symptoms so I know it is not related to my code.

Google documentation points to using Creator Studio to get realtime views (48 hrs estimated view count etc).  I'd like to get this info in my c# UWP app, ideally using the Google dotnet libraries.  Anyone know if it's actually possible at all?  I cannot find any reference to metrics or dimensions that allow the realtime estimated view count for a channel.

Comment: Could you please link to the documentation for the realtime reports for Youtube analytics i didnt know they allowed that.    If there is an API for that i havent seen it.  The one ou are using now is not for real time

Comment: Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/). The page suggests the following: _The YouTube Analytics API supports real-time targeted queries to generate custom YouTube Analytics reports._

Comment: then you are using the correct one.  The client library just access the api i should work out of the box.   I suggest testing here to see if it works there https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Comment: So I guess this is exactly my question  Is it actually possible using these api's or not?  Also, can't find the link to the documentation that mentions using Creator Studio right now.  Will post when I find it again.  Been going around in circles for too long.

Comment: The documentation says that its possible then it should be possible.   I have never seen it before though.   I dont know what creator studio is so i cant help you with that.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. I have already tested this using the API explorer. Finding is that is does NOT show the views in realtime.  Can't get to the last 48 hours of estimated views this way it seems.

Comment: if its not working in api explorer i would post it as a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600

Comment: Cool thanks.  Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6096647?hl=en) that talks about the YouTube Analytics Realtime Report, Creator Studio Classic and YouTube Studio beta just for reference.  Will consider raising a bug. Thanks for the advice and your help